# Conditional Formats, can i name them

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Working on a situation where if i cant logically go through and add a new range of cells to a pre-defined Conditional Format then i will have to format close to 1000 rows.

After reading this article on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821841.aspx), it says Index or Name, obviously someone got lazy and just copy/pasted information.  But by the off chance, can a name be associated with a Conditional Format?

If not, then how do i control order in which the Formats are read?  They are all formula formats, and none are the prefab types.

Comment: do you want a `VBA` solution? You could create a macro to loop through each cell in a range applying formatting to each cell based on a set of conditions in the program. Easier just to use the built in conditional formatting.

Comment: The problem is i am making it as user insensitive as possible.  There are already alot of processing happening during load but majority based on Ribbon Button clicks.  Im looking for the easiest and best solution but seems once again Microsoft didnt think beyond door when implementing a useful tool.  Guess ill be pre-formatting 10,000 rows and about 20 columns since they havent implemented a proper collection.  Can't wait for the day they transition away from VB6 and into the .Net framework

Comment: unfortunately i still don't fully understand your question. "pre-formatting 10,000 rows and 20 columns" ...I've got hundreds of workbooks with this amount of are pre-formatted cells. I would never add _conitional_ formatting to this size range though!!

Comment: Unfortunately, its the best solution for the situation.  otherwise if i did a PastSpecial Value/Format every time i needed to copy data over it would then bring over the Cond-Format and the formats for a Worksheet would exponentially, if not indefinitely, grow every time the process executed without preformatting 10,000 row over 20 columns.  I only have 1 format per condition that covers the effected 10,000 row x 20row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SetFirstPriority`method to order your format conditions, or just create them as you go, with each condition coming after the previous one, as in the below code.

```
Dim myRange As Range

Set myRange = Selection

With myRange

    'First condition
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=A6=125"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
        .TintAndShade = -0.899960325937681
    End With
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).StopIfTrue = False

    'second condition
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=A6=250"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
        .TintAndShade = -0.899960325937681
    End With
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).StopIfTrue = False

End With
```

Comment: (this is basically a recorded macro)

Comment: if you record a macro, it will set any new rule as the first priority, so not really.

Comment: yeah its the lack of proper control of a collection that is really causing most of the problems.  Thank you for the help, it will help me implement a ad-hoc VSTO library for future developments against for the project.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer #1**: I see no way name a conditional formatting rule.

**Answer #2**: You can control the order the conditional formatting is applied.  Click on Conditional Formatting | Manage Rules.  From there, you can use the up/down buttons to move rules up and down in the list.  You can even mark the checkbox to stop processing rules if the selected rule is `true'.

**Comment**: Not sure why you tagged this `excel-vba`.  There doesn't seem to be any `VBA` element to your question.

Comment: cause im doing this in VBA.  The end-user will only see a fabricated ribbonUI that we have designed/created and all others will be stripped away.  So the end-user wont have access to such ribbon tab/groups that normal files might see.

Comment: You can control the rule order with the `.FormatConditions(index).Priority` property or `SetFirstPriority`/`SetLastPriority` methods.  (see http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2005/10/14/conditional-formatting-using-vba-some-examples.aspx)

Comment: tyvm....ill be working on something to utilize these methods but for now seems ill have to preformat an over-exorbidant amount of row/cols in order to get the desired effect ;(